# Assign a bash command result in a Cheetah variable

Tags: bash, cheetah

I'm currently trying to put the result of a bash command into a Cheetah variable :

```
#set $name = #echo '$input.element_identifier' + ".phy" | cut -d _ -f 1
```

*'$input.element_identifier'* Being (sort of) a link to the name of a previous input file (I try to do that in the  section of a xml wrapper for Galaxy, a bioinformatics software)

My problem is that Cheetah does not recognize the '$' in the echo command ... I've tried a lot of other syntaxes but the problem remains the same (so I can't know if the rest of the command is correct)

This is a rather specific question (linked to the administration and use of the Galaxy software), I hope I'm clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes with your current approach:

1. `#echo` doesn't execute OS commands, `#echo` executes Python expressions.
2. `#echo` doesn't return result, `#echo` puts the result into the output stream (HTML or whatever the output is).

To execute an OS command you need `os.system()` or `subprocess.Popen()`. To assign the result of the command you certainly need to catch command's stdout, `Popen` suites the task better.

Something like that:

```
#import subprocess
#set $name = $subprocess.check_output($input.element_identifier + '.phy | cut -d _ -f 1', shell=True)
```

Comment: `shell=True`, not `use_shell=True`. That said, this doesn't *at all* look safe to me (in terms of avoiding shell injection attacks) -- injecting arbitrary strings in locations parsed as code by a shell is an easy route to security compromises. If you can run Python code, why not do the work of extracting the filename component we want in Python?

Comment: ...if you *did* want to make it secure while still using `shell=True`, you'd move the substitutions out-of-band from the code itself -- `subprocess.Popen(['shell script here using "$1"', '_', "this becomes $1"], shell=True)` is an example of how do this safely (if the shell script is under your control as author, but the value substituted for `this becomes $1` is not).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for `shell=True`! I always forget the hell of parameters for `subprocess`.

Comment: Allright, I tried things (a bit randomly again) and this command seems to work (I don't have an error at that point anymore) : `#set $name = $subprocess.check_output(["echo", $input.element_identifier'.phy', "|", "cut", "-d", "_", "-f", "1"] )`. Another command, `#subprocess.call(["mv", $input.element_identifier'.phy', $new_file])`, does not recognize "$" either ...

Comment: Why use shell when you have Python? Use `os.rename()`.